# Complex analysis - Understanding singularity problems and connection between "Residue theorem" and "Taylor" and "singularities"

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, singularity

I know there is alot of information at internet, saw a topic here related this concept.
But I like to make sure I understand.
A)
Regarding $f\left(z\right)=z\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$
We know it has singularity problem at $z=0$, so we can know if it is analytic at 0 or not by knowing it residue. By using taylor series, we will receive that $c_{-1}=0$ ( it has only even negative power). Does it mean I can say that $f(z)$ is entire in $\mathbb{C}$? since its residue is 0 and thus it has a antiderivative ( If I remember correctly ).

B)
Same with $g\left(z\right)=\frac{\sin\left(z\right)}{z}$, from its taylor series we can say pretty much that it is entire is $\mathbb{C}$ ( that I Know for sure, I proved, but just to make sure here ).

C)
Regarding $h\left(z\right)=\frac{z}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}\:$.
This function is a little problematic for me, according to studies, this function is not analytic in $0$ and at $\frac 1 {\pi k}$, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
However, from its taylor series we will actually receive that $$\frac{z}{\frac{1}{z}-\frac{3!}{z^3}+O\left(z^5\right)}$$ and it is actually a number that has $\frac{p\left(z\right)}{q\left(z\right)}$ such that $deg\left[p\left(z\right)\right]>deg\left[q\left(z\right)\right]$.
So how is it possible it is not analytic at 0? or the other infinite points.

What am I missing here? I do not know why I am having hard time understanding this concept.

Comment: Don't try to put the full question in the title, elide stuff because you can't fit if, then force the reader to read through the question to get finally to the definition of $h.$ Just summarize the question in the title, then start your question with, you know, your question

Comment: Yea, I actually tried to summarize it, I thought I have to put the functions there, I will edit it :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Done, hope it is good now :)

Comment: $h$ doesn't have Taylor series at $0$ as $h$ isn't holomorphic at $0.$

Comment: $f(1/z)+f(-1/z)$ with $f$ analytic  always has residue $0,$ but it doesn't mean we can make it analytic at $z=0.$

Comment: What about $1/z^2$?

Comment: Ahh.. I am confused... so in order to for it to be holomorphic at 0, what do I need exactly? and why is it not holomorphic at 0 then? I can not understand :\

Comment: Regarding h and g, I actually got help, Edd answered me :)
my problem right now sadly is only with A)

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay that pretty much I understand.. about$\frac 1 z$, that is a pole with order two. so in order for it to be analytic at a point. what do I need? that is the thing that confuses me. if the point has removable singularity, like with $B)$, does it mean that it is analytic at that point?

Comment: @LearningToCode Remember, for a function to be analytic at $w \in \mathbb{C}$, it has to allow a power series expansion around $w$. This means, in particular, that it cannot allow terms of the form $(z-w)^{-n},$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Having zero residue is not enough.

Comment: Oh right, Thanks!! Forgot it all, did not touch this subject this first period :\ very much appreciated. can say I understand all here fully!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's quickly review your points.

**A)** $f(z) = z \sin(1/z)$ actually has an *essential singularity* at $z = 0.$ You can see this by using the power series expansion that defines $\sin z$ around $z = 0$ to obtain the Laurent series for $f$ around this point:
$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \frac{1}{z^{2n}}.$$
As you correctly saw, the residue of $f$ at $z = 0$ is $0,$ but since $f$ has infinitely many negative-power terms, it has an essential singularity there, so the residue is not that useful here.

**B)** $g(z) = \sin (z) / z$ has a *removable singularity* at $z = 0,$ since it has limit at that point, so you can actually extend $g$ by defining $g(0) := 1,$ and in this way it becomes an entire function.

**C)** $h(z) = z / \sin(1/z)$ cannot be analytic at $z = 0$ because this point is not an *isolated singularity*, i.e., you cannot find an open disk around $z = 0$ such that $f$ is analytic on the punctured disk. You can see this by noting that every point in the set
$$\left\{ \frac{1}{k\pi} \, \middle\vert \, k \in \mathbb{Z} , \, k \neq 0 \right\}$$
is a simple pole of $\sin(1/z),$ and that $0$ is an accumulation point of this set. There's not much work to be done once the singularity is not isolated, as far as I know.

Comment: Wow, first of all, thanks for the Huge answer!!!.......
A) Regarding the residue, how is it 1? since the residue of a function at a point is basically $\frac 1 z$, and here the power is even only. so it wont reach power of $z^{-1}$..............        
B) Regarding that, Okay, that I understand pretty much, Thanks!..............C) Huge Thanks!!!........... My problem is only with A) right now.

Comment: @LearningToCode Oops, sorry! The Laurent series of $f$ is correct but I forgot to multiply that $z$ in my head when I was writing about the residue, I don't know what happened to me. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Oh did not notice it myself lol. It is all good! you helped me alot. I will see the edit afterwards and see if I have any problem. Huge thanks!

Comment: I understood, you are correct, if there is infinitely negative power, then it is essential singularity. Thanks!